# How to avoid memory leak where function returning an array

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks

In the following code pointer *A* had different address before calling the function *copy()*. Once the *copy()* is executed, pointer *A* got the address of pointer *B* which is declared in *copy()*. So, within *main()* when *free(A)* is executed, it's freeing the memory assigned to the pointer *B* in *copy()*. Now the problem is how to deallocate pointer *A* assigned within *main()* ?  Is there any memory leaks in the following code? How to prevent it?

Here is the code:

```
#define size 10
int *copy(int *A){
int i;
int *B = (int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
printf("address of B=%p\n",B);
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
       B[i]=A[i]+1;
    }
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
   printf("%d ",B[i]);
   }
 printf("\n ");
 return B;
 }

 int main(){
     int i;
     int *A = (int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
     printf("address of A before copy()=%p\n",A);

     for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        A[i] = i;
        }
        A=copy(A);
      printf("address of A after copy()=%p\n",A);
     for(i=0;i<size;i++){
         printf("%d ",A[i]);    
         }
     printf("\n");
     free(A);
     return 0;
     }
```

And here is the output:

```
   address of A before copy()=0x1e64010
   address of B=0x1e64040
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
   address of A after copy()=0x1e64040
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any memory leaks in the following code?

Yes, there's potentially a memory leak from these lines:

```
int *A = (int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int));

int *A = copy(A);   // <-- Do NOT allocate and then point the pointer to somewhere else
```

That is because you allocated memory for `A`, and then you pointed `A` to somewhere else, thus loosing the handle to free the memory *initially* allocated.

NOTE:

- In this particular case, though, you might get away with it because it happened in `main()` - and the memory could be deallocated by the OS itself when the program exits.
- Generally speaking, however, this kind of code would cause memory leak, especially when the function is not `main()`. Also, it's a bad practice leaving it the OS to do the clean up for you.

> how to deallocate pointer A assigned within main() ?

How to make it works - here's a suggestion:

- Declare a 2nd pointer `B` within `main()`
- Then call `copy` to copy/modify content from original array.

The code should look like this:

```
 int *A = (int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int));

 // Initialize A
 for( i=0;i<size;i++ )
 {
    A[i] = i;
 }

 // Copy A to B, and modify the content.
 int *B = copy(A);   // <-- 2nd pointer
```

And at the end, `free` both pointers:

```
free( A );
free( B );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one doubt here, what is the best way to update A with copy(A) before freeing B in main()?

Comment: If the only thing you wanted to is to modify `A`, then do not return `int *` in your `copy` function, simply use `void copy(int *A)` - that would allow you to modify `A` directly. Also change the name of the function to something else, not `copy`, maybe `update()` would be a better name.